# How should I pass the reference of an object to another object of the same class?

Tags: c#, oop

```
public Class A
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public Class B
{ 
    A obj1 = new A(); 
    obj.Name = "ABCDEFGH";
}

public Class C
{ 
    A obj2 = ...
}
```

How should I pass the reference of obj1 to obj2. So that all the data of obj1 like the Name in this case will be accessible here as well?

Comment: One way to make the question a lot *less* confusing is to show code rather than describing it.

Comment: can you type out some legible code, so we can know what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe type out an attempt of what you want done, I cant understand the question.

Comment: Add a copy constructor to class B. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor)

Comment: Its actually very confusing as you've given no code. I'm trying to picture what the code is, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335918/visual-c-sharp-access-instance-of-object-created-in-one-class-in-another

Comment: @3Dave or implement the `ICloneable` interface, which does pretty much the same.

Comment: The code example makes it much clearer. However, note this code doesn't compile. You can't change the value of `Name` outside of the method. Either move `obj.Name = "ABC";` into a method or into a constructor for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public class B
{ 
    A obj1 = new A(); 

    public void Foo()
    {
        A obj1 = new A(); 
        obj1.Name = "ABCDEFGH";

        C c = new C(obj1);
    }
}

public class C
{ 
    A obj2;

    // Constructor is called when created
    public C(A a) => obj2 = a; // obj2 will now have the same reference 
}
```

This is called dependency injection. The constructor is called whenever we use the `new` keyword. When we do that, we have to pass in a reference to `A`.

Now, both `obj2` and `obj1` point to the same instance of `A` so if `Name` is changed again, that change will be observed by both classes.

Keep in mind, it is possible for all instances of class `C` to not share the same instance of `obj2`. That will depend on what they are given in their constructors.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things to consider:

1. What properties does class B have?  Are they all value types or are there reference types?
2. Once you have two identical instances, will class A and C change their copy's internal state?  If so, do you want those changes to be reflected or will they diverge?

Generally speaking though, you should instantiate X1 outside of class A and pass it in to its constructor so that you can clone it and also pass it into class B's constructor.  Beware that cloning X1 naively may cause unexpected results if you have say, a list as one of its properties (because then both X1 and X2 will point to the same list instead of each having their own identical copy of the list).

There are other options like using a readonly interface but I'd need more specifics.

```
public class ClassB
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public List<string> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA
{
    private ClassB classB;
    public ClassA(ClassB classB) => this.classB = classB;
}

public class ClassC
{
    private ClassB classB;
    public ClassC(ClassB classB) => this.classB = classB;
}

int number = 10;
var fooList = new List<string>();

ClassB X1 = new ClassB() { Number = number, Foo = fooList };

// both A and B have the same reference to X1 so you will need to consider thread safety if you are modifying X1
var classA = new ClassA(X1);
var classB = new ClassB(X1);
```