# C# Create object "user" after login and use it in application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have question, how to create object/variables, and using it in another places in application?

I have class "User" with variables e.g. Name, Surname, privilege and method getPrivilage. After login I'm creating new User - loggedUser - but.. how in another form check privilage my "loggedUser"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual C# - Access instance of object created in one class in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335918/visual-c-sharp-access-instance-of-object-created-in-one-class-in-another)

Comment: My problem has been solved by add "static" modifier to my "public loggedUser".

Answer (score 0):

The best thing will be you can inherit the User class in your loggedUser class thus which gives you the Privilege property too.

**CODE**

```
 //Inheriting the User class as the LoggerUser will also be the type of User.    
 LoggedUser : User
 {
    //Logged User Functionality or In Constructor you can set the privilage property.
 }

var loggedUserObj = new LoggedUser(); 
var loggedUsePrivilage = loggedUserObj.privilage;
```